# Can we say "I sat in the front and my sister sat in the back of the dolphin"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

We often say "**in the front**" when we are inside something not on something.

For example, "**She always sits in the front of the class.**"

[image]

Can we use  "**in the front**" when we are on something like a motorbike or a dolphin?

For example, "**I sat in the front and my sister sat in the back of the dolphin**"?

Comment: [We often say "in the front" ] No, it's either "in front of" (=facing) or "at the front of" (= in the foremost position) BTW, a dolphin's foremost and most rear parts of the body are a beak and a tail.

Comment: I would say _at the front of the class_. You sit _in the front_ of a car, but _at_ or _on the front_ of something that doesn't enclose you.

Comment: @KateBunting, but "she sat on the front of the dolphin" may mean "her back is sticking to the mouth of the dolphin"

Comment: No-one would seriously understand it to mean that she was sitting on the dolphin's _head_. You normally ride on the back of an animal, so in this context 'the front'  implies 'the front section of the part you sit on'.

Answer (score 2):

*I sat in front of my sister on the dolphin,* succinctly expresses the action depicted in your illustration.

Without the picture to aid in understanding, you may want to add *...that we were riding,* onto the end of the sentence.  A listener probably would not assume you were riding a dolphin unless you made it clear.

To sit *in the front* of something requires that you be inside the thing you are sitting in the front of.  You can sit *in the front* of the train (meaning a train car at the beginning of the line of train cars or the first row of a particular train car) and you can sit *in the front of the class[room]* (meaning you are sitting in the front row of a classroom).  You cannot, however, sit in the front of a dolphin unless a Dolphin is a type of boat.